# I cannot disable CHKDSK on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, reboot, chkdsk

Every time I happen to shut off my computer manually, it runs automatically a CHKDSK check before starting up.
I tried to edit the registry in

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager key BootExecute

The string was

> autocheck autochk /k:C

It means that my drive C: [I have it on the letter C:] is **already disabled** in fact the /k:C means that the C driver *will not be checked any more*.
I did not schedule any CHKDSK in my "Scheduled Tasks"! It just starts running each and every time I reboot my computer normally after I shut it off in an incorrect way through the power button [holding it and after a few seconds realising it and then pushing it once again].

Besides, in CMD the C: drive is NOT damaged [fsutil dirty query C:].

Should I change the value

> autocheck autochk /k:C
>   to the string 
>   autocheck autochk *

I suppose it could lead to data corruption, isn't it?! .. I had better be careful.

I tried also to go to CMD [always as administrator from system32] and enter

> chkntfs /X C:

The result is "The type of the file systen is NTFS."

So, what should I do if none of these resolution fixed my problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/stuck-chkdsk-use-fix-right-way/):

- Why Does CHKDSK Run at Every Start Up for Me?

There’s [something wrong with your hard drive](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/keep-an-eye-on-your-hdd-ssd-health-with-hard-disk-sentinel/). That’s the short answer.

What exactly the issue is, however, is much harder to answer. Perhaps a critical system file has been corrupted or deleted. Perhaps there are a lot of bad sectors that aren’t getting dealt with. Remember, Check Disk won’t fix those, unless you tell it to do so. Until whatever the problem is gets fixed, Windows may try to figure out the problem by running Check Disk every start-up.

- How Do I Stop CHKDSK From Running Every Start-Up?

The answer is simple, but not necessarily easy – fix whatever is wrong with Windows. There could be just one thing wrong, or dozens. The number of possible fixes is really unknown, but let’s go through the easiest and most common fixes for you to try.